# Chain summing in Excel

Tags: excel-2007

I have this table:

```
   Sendedr Reciever Price  SumAllParice 
   Dan      Moshe    A
   Kate     Sara     G
   Beth     Kith     U
   Moshe    Kate     X
```

(actually, it's much more bigger, it's just an example). I what to sum all the prices like this: "dan" is sending "moshe" A, and the (according the table) "moshe" sending "kate" X, and then "kate" will send to sara G so in the "sumAllPrices" in the first row will be A+G+X. in the second row will be G (because after kate sending sara, sara dosn,t send anyone else), in the third row will be U, and in the fourth row will be X+G (because after moshe sending kate, kate will send to sara. How can i do this in Excel?

Comment: Can a single sender appear more than once in the sender column?  If so, I'm not aware of a way you can accomplish this with built-in excel functions, and I think you'll be forced to write some code.

Comment: One sender can appear more then once, but all the line is unique. and what code can i write?

Comment: You might want to learn about VBA macros in excel.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905419.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. it's a little bit limited' but it works!

[image]

- I entered an image because it all meesed up when i copied it from the excel...

Explentaion:  The 1rst iteration is to sum the first row with the second (e.g if Tin sending Dan, and Dan sending moshe, so it will be R+A). The second iteration act the same, but it sums the sum column with the first iteration by those rules, and so on, untill the answer is the sum of the sum column with the third iteration column.